# Is it possible in Ubuntu to make mouse clicks and hotkeys trigger when a button is lifted rather than when pressed?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, mouse, keyboard-layout

In Windows to call up the context menu I have to release the RMB.
In Ubuntu the context menu is called up, when I press RMB. When I release, the click on the context menu item is triggered. This is very unusual. It is impossible to predict where the context menu will open. And sometimes by pressing and releasing the RMB I not only call up the context menu, but, for example, create an empty folder, which is why the context menu is hidden.

It's the same with hotkeys. In Windows, to switch the keyboard layout I need to release Alt+Shift. In Ubuntu I need to hold down. Perhaps I don't want to switch the keyboard layout, I want to hold down some other keys to perform a different combination. But it won't work because the keyboard layout will change.

Is it possible in Ubuntu to make mouse clicks and hotkeys trigger when a button is lifted, rather than when pressed? How to do it?

Comment: At least the RBM it's difficult because it's handled differently per-app

Comment: RMB = Right Mouse Button?

Comment: It might also depend on the exact desktop environment? E.g. Gnome, or KDE, or LXDE/LXQt. It would be useful to specify which one you use, perhaps along its version number. Ubuntu Mate has Gnome v2, Ubuntu 20.04 has Gnome v3, and more recent vanilla Ubuntus have Gnome v4.

Comment: @Levente Yes, it's the Right Mouse Button.

Comment: @Levente, I'm using official Ubuntu 22.04.